# How can I blend meshes together where they intersect?

Tags: unity, shaders, models, 3d-meshes, materials

In a lot of my scenes I have things like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

All the places I've circled are places where a prefab overlaps with another one or with the terrain.

**Is there any way to make those lines softer/more natural and blend together more?**

When I can, I try and hide the lines with trees or other items, but that doesn't work in every case.

I wonder if I can solve this with something like the soft particles effect. Soft particles in Unity help blur the line between a particle system and a rendered mesh. This keeps you from having jarring hard cut offs and straight lines in something that's supposed to be amorphous. (That's as far as my understanding goes) Can I use something like this to blend my prefabs together?